# Do Metro app data input forms have save and cancel buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro, lob

I plan to write a LOB desktop app using WPF but in metro style but I haven't found enough sample apps that feature data input/editing forms. Most metro apps are read-only dashboards or entertainment apps.

If anyone could point me to good sample apps, or guidelines that state what a data input form should be like. I assume popup modal forms with OK/Cancel buttons are a thing of the past, but what are they replaced with?

Thanks for any pointers or opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Basically, you need to consider the nature of the data, the workflow and its consequences. Sometimes is reasonable to use autosaving, sometimes is better to use OK/Cancel approach. You should take into account risks, user's responsibility for the data, commit consequences, confidence, how many rows and how frequently they update at once/per day/etc, whether they have subitems, whether it is easy to fill in or they need to think a lot or whether it is more a trial-and-error form, whether there are interconnections between fields and lots of other things.

And do a lot of user testing.

Ok/Cancel is not think of the past, it just evolved. If you look on the apps carefully, you might find that the Ok button is quite frequent (even it is named differently like Post, Publish etc.) and the Cancel button is replaced with clicking somewhere else, clicking on the Back button somewhere, using the hardware back button etc.

PS: You are correct, the touch apps are usually oriented on the consumer segments as they does not work such well for full-time writing (and there is lack of matured apps for that). Don't try to stick to metro too hard if your users will use mouse and keyboard. It does not work so well on its own with them. For sure, you can inspire yourself with some of the ideas but do the transition carefully.

Comment: Thanks for these useful tips, even though it should be obvious. I'm still looking for inspiration but there is a dearth of Metro data input apps. Shame because I do like the styling.

Comment: Facebook, Calendar, OneNote, Mail. Carefully check the Productivity and Finance categories these are the ones which has a reasonable percentage of apps with inputs. Maybe some apps allowing you to write and share your recipes.

Comment: Thanks alik for the tip on searching productivity apps. Saw a few that I like. Though I'm actually basing my app around the DevExpress Realtor demo app - a nice metro style app even though it's a desktop app.